# How can i use the Garbage Collector?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Knowing nothing about the GC and never having the need to use it (or so i think), what is a typical use there of, and how can i / my system benefit if i up skill myself and learn more about the GC?

**UPDATE**
...how can i make things easier for the GC?

Comment: In a word: don't.

Comment: Define "easier". Do you have a problem with garbage collection? Can you describe it in your question?

Comment: Under most circumstances, not touching the .NET GC is correct. Here is an discussion for a specific instance that it may be beneficial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> UPDATE ...how can i make things easier
>   for the GC?

The easiest way of making things easier for the GC is to let it do it's job without interfering.  It optimizes when it needs to run on it's own.

I would look into when to use a the [Finalizer](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33167/0/page/2) in C#.  That is one area where you can potentially help the GC out.

Understanding the [Large Object Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx) may be of some benefit as well as this can potentially cause problems.

http://techiemate.blogspot.com/2009/04/garbage-collection-in-net.html

Comment: Thanx for the links, helping me understanding it more already

Comment: Is there any circumstance when using a finalizer helps the GC? I suppose that *not* using a finalizer helps the GC because it then doesn't need to track your object on the finalization/freachable queues etc.

Answer (score 14):

The typical use of the GC is to not use it at all and just let the CLR handle everything for you.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to use the Garbage Collector is...

**Don't try to use it!**

Let it do its own thing. Almost any time people try to play with the GC to make it "more efficient" they wind up inhibiting it and actually making it worse at its job.

Comment: The best way to use the GC is to make less G.  :-)  I've frequently seen naive algorithms that, when replaced by slightly smarter one that produces 1/10th the G, runs several times faster.  GCs these days are very good, but they're no match for doing less work in the first place, and no GC I've seen is smart enough to recognize an inefficient algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The GC isn't like the destructor you'd define in C++.  That is you do not need to define it and deallocate previously allocated memory.  The whole point of the GC is that it is automatic.
My recommendation is give us more information about what you are trying to do / understand because this does not sound safe.

Comment: What garbage collector in c++?

Comment: like mentioned... i know nothing about GC, and would like to know if there is a benefit of knowing more about it :)

Comment: @Joe - I was referring to ones own implementation of the Destructor ~MyObject().

Answer (score 1):

To make things easier to the GC, always call Dispose() on any object the supports the IDisposable interface.

Comment: The GC has absolutely nothing to do with `Dispose` and `IDisposable`.

Comment: Not directly, but `Dispose` and `IDiposable` are mechanisms to allow skipping terminators on classes who need them and THUS make thinks easy for the garbage collector. Other classes *should* present no issues...

Answer (score 1):

A few points on coding with GC in mind:

1. Always make sure to unregister event handlers when you're no longer using them.  This is the most common way that objects are kept alive well past their intended lifetime and can also cause bugs if a Disposed object is having event handlers called.
2. If you're doing interop with unmanaged code, you'll need to be more cognizant of any sharing of managed memory with the unmanaged code.  You may need to use pinning and/or GC.KeepAlive to help the GC understand what your unmanaged code needs.  Try to keep pinning to a minimum, as it makes things harder on the GC.
3. You should almost never need to implement a finalizer.  If the class does have a finalizer, it should also implement the same cleanup as IDisposable and call `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` after disposal, as this helps the GC to efficiently clean up after your class.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't notice that you're using the GC, then you are using it, and you're using it right.

Knowing about the internals of the GC only starts to matter if you're using it wrongly.

Comment: PInvoke is an obvious counter-example. Even in the context of self-contained C# code, you still need to understand the concept of reachability in order to write array-based data structures that don't leak.

Answer (score 0):

It can always be useful to understand how it works; but in most cases, you won't need to worry too much.

When you start allocating non-managed resources (or objects that do), it's worth reading up on the [IDisposable pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/idisposable.aspx) so that you can control when the resources are freed (or "deterministic finalisation" if you want to sound knowledgeable when talking with peers).

Answer (score 0):

In the style of memory management typically used in C, the information which tracks which areas of the heap are free or allocated is separate from the information which indicates what areas are actually used.  When information on the heap is no longer needed, code must explicitly mark it as unallocated or else it may remain allocated forever.

A garbage-collection-based system regards all the heap-object references in the system as the definitive indicator for which objects are used.  Because it would be impractical to scan all the object references in the system every time an object was allocated, the system effectively "batches" the work: as long as free memory space still exists on the heap, memory is simply allocated to objects sequentially.  No attempt is made to reclaim any space until the heap gets too full.

An object will be considered to be "used" if any thread holds a reference to it in a local variable, or if any global variable holds a reference to it, or if object which is considered "used" holds a reference to it in any field.  The compiler can usually tell if a local variable that holds a reference to an object will never actually be used, but it cannot make such determinations with global variables or object fields.  If an object which is going to be useful holds an object reference which is never again actually going to be used, that reference should be set to null (Nothing in VB).  If this is not done, the useless object will be "kept alive" as long as the useful object is.  If the useful object is something like an application's main form, the result may be a memory leak that persists as long as the application remains open.

Comment: This is a decent description of GC circa 1960 but no production GCs work like this today. Incrementality and concurrency are used to avoid batching because it used to incur embarrassingly-long pauses. Instead of deferring collection until the heap fills, garbage is collected regularly with effort focussed on recently-allocated objects.

Comment: While most modern garbage-collection systems use generations so most collections won't have to examine everything, that's an implementation detail.  Many common garbage collectors operate in stop-the-world batch mode, and yes--that can sometimes cause annoying pauses.  The key point to understand is that once memory is allocated in a GC system, it will be reclaimed when, and only when, the GC discovers that no rooted references to it exist.

Comment: There's often no way to explicitly tell the garbage-collector or allocator that a certain block of memory won't be used anymore, because the allocator wouldn't care.  When memory is allocated, the allocator will either grab a chunk off the free block at the end of the heap (assuming the free block is big enough) or else it will perform a garbage-collection cycle and hope that frees up enough space.  The allocator won't try to use any other chunk of memory to fill the request.

Comment: "The allocator won't try to use any other chunk of memory to fill the request". The context here is C# and .NET will actually either do a pointer-bump allocation into gen0 or it will allocate into the large object heap if the requested size is big enough.

Comment: @Jon Harrop: It's true the .net allocator has goofy semantics for "large objects", the reasoning behind which totally escapes me (I can understand some benefit for having large objects allocated separately in a heap that tries to exploit holes, but the actual LOH implementation in .net 2.0 seems like it's doing practically everything else all wrong), and the LOH could theoretically exploit early notification that an object is no longer needed.  Of course, letting large objects die in gen0 or gen1 would probably help just as much.

Comment: "the reasoning behind which totally escapes me". The Large Object Heap (LOH) was created to solve the problem of the moving generational collector wasting effort moving large objects back and forth. However, the LOH is prone to fragmentation and I've had problems with aggressive recycling of large objects causing out-of-memory errors on 32-bit machines even when there is plenty of space left because it is so fragmented and .NET is incapable of compacting it.

Comment: @Jon Harrop: I recognize that there is value in handling large objects differently from small ones.  What I don't understand are the reasons behind having large objects start in Gen2, having them allocated with granularity smaller than 4k, having 8KB arrays of Double stored in the LOH, etc.  Even if one didn't bother actually reclaiming space from LOH objects until Gen2, I see no reason they shouldn't start out in Gen0 so as to avoid unnecessary promotion of objects to which they hold references.

Answer (score 0):

> Knowing nothing about the GC and never having the need to use it (or so i think), what is a typical use there of, and how can i / my system benefit if i up skill myself and learn more about the GC?

You can exploit knowledge about garbage collection to improve the throughput and latency of the software you write.

> UPDATE ...how can i make things easier for the GC?

Use value types to reduce the number of pointers in the heap. Use trees of objects instead of long arrays to make heap traversal more incremental and reduce latency. Avoid writing references into mutables in the heap because this incurs a write barrier and worsens both throughput and latency.